# How to get recent added recode id from mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express, npm

I am adding new user information in mysql db. how can i get recent added record id so that i can create user login detail. Please mind the environment of this Application. 
I'm using 
 1. Windows 
 2. NPM, Express 
 3. MySQL
Here is my code.

```
var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            var data = {
                username    : input.username,
                pswd : input.pswd,
                email   : input.email,
                phone   : input.phone 
            };
            var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO customer set ? ",data, function(err, rows)
            {
                if (err)
                    console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );
                //console.log(query.sql);
                    res.redirect('/dashboard');
            });
        });
```

Comment: how recent added record id will help in creating user login details???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the `insertId` attribute:

```
var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO customer set ? ",data, function(err, result)
{
  ...
  console.log(result.insertId);
  ...
});
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting a row into a table with an auto increment primary key, you can retrieve the insert id like this:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts customer set ? ",data,  function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.insertId);
});
```

Reference:- https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row